# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 4: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, utf-8, psychopy

I actually have no Idea how to solve this, cause I never used Python before. I just can use Psychopy to generate a script in Python, but I dont find the mistake here. Would be great if you know the answer or you can give me a hint how to find one!:

```
###################### Running: D:\LTD_Liste1_lastrun.py #######################
pyo version 0.8.5 (uses single precision)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\LTD_Liste1_lastrun.py", line 77, in <module>
    Target = sound.Sound('A', secs=-1)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\sound\backend_pyo.py", line 279, in __init__
    init(rate=sampleRate)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\sound\backend_pyo.py", line 128, in init
    audioDriver, outputID = _bestDriver(devNames, devIDs)
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\sound\backend_pyo.py", line 26, in _bestDriver
    preferredDrivers = prefs.general['audioDriver']
  File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\configobj.py", line 563, in __getitem__
    new = [_check(entry) for entry in val]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 4: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Could you show here first 3 lines of D:\LTD_Liste1_lastrun.py ?

Comment: Have you set the duration of the sound to MINUS 1 second (`secs=-1`)? Durations can only be positive.

Comment: What is the value of the Preferenes -> General -> audio driver setting?

Comment: What version of PsychoPy do you have installed (the exact version number please)? We fixed one issue a bit like this (but I'm not sure it's the same) that was caused by unicode characters in the names of audio devices, so upgrading to the latest PsychoPy could fix it. If not then @hoechenberger is right - we need to know about your audio hardware names if possible

Comment: @RedEyed  The first three lines are #!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

Comment: @Jon I installed the latest one, but the window ist says I would use 0.8.5

Comment: @JonasLindeløv I didnt set the time to negative. The sound shall appear 1sec after Trialbegin and last 3.5 seconds, I dont know why it says -1

Comment: 0.8.5 is the version of pyo, not the version of PsychoPy. Go to the menu `>help>about...` or check the very first line of the Output panel when you open PsychoPy. It should be something like 1.85.3

Answer (score 1):

This sound like the utf8-encoding bug in the 1.85.3 version that appears mainly on windows 7.
If you try to go to File > Preferences and the same error appears, then it is most likely this bug.

The solution, that worked for me was to uninstall version 1.85.3 and install 1.85.2

Feel free to delete/edit my answer, as soon as this bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to remove 'pyo' from the audio library (Preference -> General) and just keep ['pygame']. It worked for me on Windows 10. I "found" this solution thanks to the comment of @hoechenberger. Huge thanks to her/him.